# Joining SQL Tables in view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a hard time battling duplicate entries when creating a view. I need a combination of fields from both tables to show in this field, however each incident has multiple radiolog entries. Therefore the join creates a row for every time the incident is referenced in the radiolog table. Here is the breakdown.

***Table 1***(Incidents)

```
callid
respoff
number
date
nature
agency(used for filtering)
```

***Table 2***(radiolog)

```
callid
xpos
ypos
logdate
```

I need the results to show where the callid matched and am using it for a specific incident. Here is what I have:

```
SELECT dbo.lwmain.respoff, 
       dbo.lwmain.number, 
       dbo.lwmain.dtrepor, 
       dbo.rlmain.xpos, 
       dbo.rlmain.ypos, 
       dbo.lwmain.nature, 
       dbo.rlmain.logdate
  FROM dbo.lwmain LEFT OUTER JOIN
       dbo.rlmain ON dbo.lwmain.callid = dbo.rlmain.callid
 WHERE (dbo.lwmain.agency = 'P16') 
   AND (dbo.lwmain.dtrepor > '2022-01-01 00:00:00.0000000')
```

Edit with photo of example data:
[Example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9r6Y.jpg)

Comment: FYI [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and should be avoided. You are far better off aliasing your objects in the `FROM` and using those to qualify your columns. This avoids the use of a feature that will be deprecated and possibly removed in a future version, and makes your code much more succinct and readable. Also don't over use parenthesis (`()`). Each your clauses in the `WHERE` do *not* need to be wrapped in them.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN?

Comment: As for your question, you say you're getting duplicates, however, you're not; if there are multiple (distinct) rows in your table `radiolog` (though this doesn't appear in your query at all?) that are related to a row in your table `Incidents` (also not in your query) then you are going to get multiple instances of the data from `Incidents`. That's how `JOIN`s are *supposed* to work. You don't, however, explain what results you're expecting. Why is getting multiple rows "bad" when that is exactly what is supposed to happy?

Comment: Because a `LEFT JOIN`, @pmbAustin , won't cause rows from the preceding table(s) to be omitted. I don't see why the OP using `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN` is a "problem" here; it's not like they are turning it into an implicit `INNER JOIN` in the `WHERE`.

Comment: If you want at most one radiolog record for a given incident (perhaps the first or last), I suggest using a CROSS APPLY or OUTER APPLY to select a specific record,  Something like: "SELECT ... FROM dbo.lwmain LW OUTER APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo.rlmain RL WHERE RL.callid = LW.callid ORDER BY RL.logdate DESC) LAST_RL WHERE ..." OUTER APPLY is like a LEFT JOIN, while CROSS APPLY is like an INNER JOIN.

Comment: Using left join was my second attempt after inner join yielded even more duplicates. Basically every incident number is unique and has nothing close to a duplicate. However, multiple radiolog entries can be associated with a single incident. For example a unit can update their status 10 times for a single incident and multiple units can be associated with the incident. I mostly need the coordinates field from the radiolog table and the latest radiolog entry timestamp.

Comment: As already mentioned - we need a [mre] with sample data and desired results. Words don't do data justice.

Comment: Sorry dale trying to find a way to export a data sample that is enough for you to see but I need to strip confidential data from it

Comment: Side note: For best performance, ensure that you have an index on rlmain(callid, logdate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the additional requirement that you only want the latest rlmain record for each call, the following should work:

```sql
SELECT LW.respoff, 
       LW.number, 
       LW.dtrepor, 
       RL_LAST.xpos, 
       RL_LAST.ypos, 
       LW.nature, 
       RL_LAST.logdate
  FROM dbo.lwmain LW
  OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT TOP 1 RL.*
      FROM dbo.rlmain RL
      WHERE RL.callid = LW.callid
      ORDER BY RL.logdate DESC
  ) RL_LAST
 WHERE (LW.agency = 'P16') 
   AND (LW.dtrepor > '2022-01-01 00:00:00.0000000')
```

Side note: Be careful of edge conditions. Although the likelihood of an exact '2022-01-01 00:00:00.0000000' dtrepor date may be small, it will be excluded by the WHERE condition above.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that a `"SELECT DISTINCT"` would help with this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.lwmain.respoff, dbo.lwmain.number, dbo.lwmain.dtrepor, 
   dbo.rlmain.xpos, dbo.rlmain.ypos, dbo.lwmain.nature, dbo.rlmain.logdate
FROM dbo.lwmain 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.rlmain ON dbo.lwmain.callid = dbo.rlmain.callid
WHERE (dbo.lwmain.agency = 'P16') 
AND (dbo.lwmain.dtrepor > '2022-01-01 00:00:00.0000000')
```

https://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: Requiring `distinct` is often a sign that the query is poorly designed.

Comment: Or at least, on this many columns. Normally it's use is against 1 or 2 columns, not 7, and that dataset is being used to populate another table, or create something like a Cartesian product between 2 small data sets (for example a list of ID's and dates).

Comment: I have already attempted this. I end up with a timeout error.